# ¿Porque ejecuta la funcion al seleccionar el radio button, pero no lo selecciona, jquery?

Tags: jquery

Buen día.
Tengo la siguiente tabla con sus registros y cada uno con su radio button:

```
<tbody id="formas_pagos" class="formas_pagos">
    <tr>
        <td class="nuevo-td">Descuento Adicional</td>
        <td class="nuevo-td">5,948.50</td>
        <td class="nuevo-td">
            <label class="label-radio item-content">
                <input type="radio" name="tipo_pago" class="tipo_pago" value="1"  />
                <span class="item-media">
                    <i class="icon icon-form-radio"></i>
                </span>
            </label>
        </td>
        <td class="label-cell">
            <input type="number" name="cantidad" class="cantidad" placeholder="Cantidad">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="nuevo-td">Tarjeta de Credito</td>
        <td class="nuevo-td">5,948.50</td>
        <td class="nuevo-td">
            <label class="label-radio item-content">
                <input type="radio" name="tipo_pago" class="tipo_pago" value="2"  />
                <span class="item-media">
                    <i class="icon icon-form-radio"></i>
                </span>
            </label>
        </td>
        <td class="label-cell">
            <input type="number" name="cantidad" class="cantidad" placeholder="Cantidad">
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Al ejecutar la siguiente función, obtengo el valor de cada una de las filas de esa tabla.

```
$('.formas_pagos').on('click','.tipo_pago', function(e){
    var tipo_pago = $(this).closest('tr');
    var valor_pago = tipo_pago.find('.tipo_pago').val();
    console.log(valor_pago);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

El problema que tengo es que al seleccionar un radio button, efectivamente manda a llamar la funcion y muestra la información, pero el detalle es de que no se queda check, al momento de que comento la función anterior, de esta forma si mantiene el check.

De antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta comentar esta línea de código

e.preventDefault();

Comment: a nu ma si es cierto, eso funciono.

Comment: Márcala como correcta si te funcionó ;)